# Is there an R function to transform a categorical variable into a binary variable?

Tags: r

I have a variable x created with the `mutate` function in the tidyverse library with integer values ranging from 0 to 11. I would like to transform this variable x into a binary variable where 0 corresponds to 0 from variable x, and 1 corresponds to any other values of x. I cannot figure out how to make this work in R, though I know the solution is probably easy and obvious once I've seen it.

Comment: `df$binary_var <- as.integer(df$x != 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `ifelse`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = c(1,11,0,2,10,3,9,0,7)
)
df$bin <- ifelse(df$v1 == 0, 0, 1)
```

Result:

```
df
  v1 bin
1  1   1
2 11   1
3  0   0
4  2   1
5 10   1
6  3   1
7  9   1
8  0   0
9  7   1
```